# is it possible to secure a specific queue in activemq with a user name and password

Tags: security, activemq-classic

I want to have a activemq broker(or a cluster).  I would like to have multiple queues in it.  I would like to give access to say a particular queue only to a particular client and no other client. IOW I don't want one client to be able to access the queue meant for another client.  How can I secure the queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use either the [JAAS or Simple Authentication Plugin.](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html).  Either of these will allow you to set up authorization to queues.

Comment: thanks.  I had found a jaas support implementation;  I wasn't sure if anyone had actually tried it.  And you have validated my thinking.